# Formula(/How) to find 2 numbers that add together to give one number and times to give another

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have $2$ numbers $a, b$. I need a formula (or a how to) to find which $2$ numbers $c,d$ will add together to give a and times together to give $b$. 
So

$c + d = a$
$c \cdot d = b$

Comment: You will end up with a quadratic equation when you replace either of c or d in the first equation with something derived from the second equation.

Comment: A typical contest question with this setup asks for the sum of the squares (or cubes) of c and d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the quadratic

$$(x-c)(x-d) = x^2 -(c+d)x + cd = x^2 - ax +b$$

Thus the roots of $$x^2 -ax + b = 0$$ are your numbers $c$ and $d$.

The roots are given by

$$\frac{ a \pm \sqrt{a^2 -4b}}{2}$$

Check this page out for more information: [Quadratic Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: Short version: it's the [Vieta formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) for the quadratic case.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not so smart to imagine that the solution has anything to do with Vieta formulae or roots of polynomials,  ;-)  I'd try the following. First, let me call your unknowns $c,d$ with letters that look like unkowns (I've tried to do the problem with $c,d$ and at a certain point I forgot which among $a,b,c,d$ were the unkowns and which the data). So let $x = c$ and $y =d$. Your system becomes

$$
\begin{align}
x + y &= a \\
xy    &= b   \ .
\end{align}
$$

Now, do what you would do in those cases. For instance, solve the first equation for $x$ in terms of $y$:

$$
x = a -y  \ .
$$

Then substitute this expression for $x$ into the second equation:

$$
(a-y)y = b \ .
$$

And, surprise!, you've got a polynomial equation

$$
y^2 -ay + b = 0
$$

that looks like the ones I've been told. (So this Vieta must have been a really smart guy, but you've rediscovered his trick.)

And, of course, once you've got the solutions $y$ of this second degree equation, you should use $x = a-y$ to find $x$... (Just to find out that if $y$ is one of the roots of the last polynomial equation, $x$ is the other one.)

Comment: "So this Vieta must have been a really smart guy, but you've rediscovered his trick." -LOL, thanks for making my day, Agusti! +1.

Comment: My pleasure.  :-)

Comment: how did you do the fancy algebraic letters? surely it will be y^2 - ay - b = 0

Comment: sorry I've tried what you said as best as I could but I don't reall understand, could you possibly do an example where a = 7 and b = 10

Comment: @Jonathan. Well, in this case you'll obtain x= 5 and y=2: 5+2= 7 and 5 x 2 = 10. As for the letters, I'm using LateX: click on the link beside "edited" and then on the one that says "view source".

Comment: Yes I know it's 5 and 2, that's why I asked for such simply numbers, but how I use your answer to get the 5 and 2? Thanks

Comment: Solve $x+y= 7$ for $x$ in terms of $y$: $x = 7-y$. Substitute this expression for $x$ in $xy = 10$. You get $(7-y)y = 10$. Which is the same as the second degree polynomial equation $y^2 -7y + 10 = 0$. Find the roots of this last equation using the formula Moron reminds you in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\rm\quad (X - c)\: (X - d) \; =\; X^2 - a\ X + b $